# Having problems adding geoflutterfire package in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, package

Please does anyone understands this problem and how to fix it?

I tried adding geoflutterfire package with other packages too in my newly created flutter project and it came up with all these errors. Please is there a solution on how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

[image: geoflutterfire package error]

Comment: The packages you use have incompatibility with each other and with your flutter version. You can try again by downgrading your flutter version.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me try it out.